# How to deal with unknown variable names in JVM sources?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, debug-symbols

While debugging code and when tracing inside JVM code, I often meet a situation, when variables are impossible to watch.

Apparently this is because variable names were wiped out from the compiled code.

What to do with it? Is there a debug version of `JVM` somewhere?

In the following screenshot it is evident, that variable is not watched on mouse hover -- only type is displayed. Simultaneously, it is visible, that variable is identified by `arg0` name in variables view in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Navigate to: `Window -> Show View -> Display` and type `System.out.println(getLastPathComponent());` in the text area that shows up at the bottom of Eclipse. Then hit the *"Execute Selected Text"* (3rd from left) button to see what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

This mean the JTree.class is compiled without debug information. All you have to do is re-compile it with debug info. To do that: copy the JTree source, and paste it into JTree.java file. 
Open cmd and type:

```
javac -g JTree.java
```

this will produce many .class files. Copy all of them back into the rt.jar
When modifing the rt.jar you may got an error that its beening used by another process, so close eclipse, and try again.
Now you should be able to debug this JTree class as you expect.

Comment: Or, since this is Eclipse, you can find the java runtime jar and attach the source.

Comment: He has the source, the problem is missing debug symbols in the .class file

Comment: Actually I think he is a she, and she is using jdk, otherwise she wouldn't have the source.